# How to create a medium application so that we can get access to medium.com OAuth API?

Tags: reactjs, json, api, oauth, medium.com-publishing-api

I cannot find the option to create Medium Application, which is a required step for getting the access to medium.com API.

I looked Medium.com everywhere but did not find any "Developers" page.

Answer (score 0):

The Medium Developers page can be found at https://developers.medium.com/